# Random selection from list with replacement

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have a list of lists, like so:

```
a = [[1,2],[2,3]]
```

I want to create a random list **with replacement** of a given size from `a`. The [`numpy.random.choice()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) method only accepts 1D arrays. I can write my own function to do this, but is there already an optimized way?

*Expected output*:

```
[[1,2],[1,2],[2,3],[2,3]] 
// the size (4 here) has to be a parameter passed to the function
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your expected output?

Comment: Do you want a list of sublists, or a list of integers? If the latter, are the lists guaranteed to contain lists of integers, or is it possible that they may be nested deeper and shallower than two levels?

Comment: @BrendanLong: I just added the expected output

Comment: @BlacklightShining: I want a list of sublists

Answer (score 11):

You can simply call [the standard library's `random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) repeatedly. No need for `numpy`.

```
>>> list_of_lists = [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
>>> sample_size = 4
>>> [random.choice(list_of_lists) for _ in range(sample_size)]
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

This is an alternative to [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) that works without replacement and lets you choose a “sample” larger than the size of the original population.

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy:

```
size = 4
a = np.array([[1,2],[2,3]])
b = np.random.randint(len(a), size = size)
a[b,:]

Out[93]:
array([[2, 3],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 3],
       [1, 2]])
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Python 3.6, you can directly use [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices).

```
random.choices(list_of_lists, k=sample_size)
## [[1, 2], [3, 4], [3, 4], [1, 2]]
```

A rough benchmark suggests this seems to be more performant on varying sample sizes than the list comprehension approach.

```
>>> list_of_lists = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> sample_size = 4

>>> %timeit [random.choice(list_of_lists) for _ in range(sample_size)]
4.49 µs ± 20.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

>>> %timeit random.choices(list_of_lists, k=sample_size)
1.99 µs ± 14.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

>>> list_of_lists *= 100
>>> sample_size *= 1000

>>> %timeit [random.choice(list_of_lists) for _ in range(sample_size)]
3.54 ms ± 28.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

>>> %timeit random.choices(list_of_lists, k=sample_size)
927 µs ± 1.39 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) library implements [`more_itertools.random_combination_with_replacement`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.random_combination_with_replacement):

```
import more_itertools as mit

list_of_lists = [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
sample_size = 4
list(mit.random_combination_with_replacement(list_of_lists, sample_size))
# [[1, 2], [1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 3]]
```